# Pandas split column of (unequal length) list into multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of codes in one column his name (Course code) that I would like to put each code is a new column

```
Semester number            Course code                          Semester AVREGE
0   13          ['ZY705']                                       S         GOOD
1   14          ['ZY405', 'ZY504', 'ZY510', 'ZY601', 'ZY605']   S         FAIL
2   15          ['ZY504', 'ZY601', 'ZY603']                     F         FAIL
3   16          ['ZY504', 'ZY704', 'ZY705']                     S         FAIL
4   17          ['ZY704']                                       F         FAIL
```

Can you guys please give me some guidance how to do that? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? Where is your code? Where is expected output? [How to ask good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: df2=data['Course code'].str.split(',', expand=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide an example of your desired output, but this might be what you're looking for.

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df['Course code'].to_list())], axis=1).drop(columns='Course code')

   Semester number Semester AVREGE        0        1        2        3        4
0               13        S   GOOD  'ZY705'     None     None     None     None
1               14        S   FAIL  'ZY405'  'ZY504'  'ZY510'  'ZY601'  'ZY605'
2               15        F   FAIL  'ZY504'  'ZY601'  'ZY603'     None     None
3               16        S   FAIL  'ZY504'  'ZY704'  'ZY705'     None     None
4               17        F   FAIL  'ZY704'     None     None     None     None
```

Comment: But when executing the code it didn't give the same result
Semester number         Semester AVREGE 0
0 13                              S GOOD ['ZY705']
1 14 S FAIL ['ZY405', 'ZY504', 'ZY510', 'ZY601', 'ZY605']
2 15 F FAIL ['ZY504', 'ZY601', 'ZY603']
3 16 S FAIL ['ZY504', 'ZY704', 'ZY705']
4 17 F FAIL ['ZY704'

Comment: if you assigned something to your dataframe's index, try doing `df = df.reset_index()` before my operation and then re-assigning your index after the operation if you still need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work, he allocated all the symbols in one column under the name 0 of which he replaced the column name course code with a 0

Comment: My answer works on your example dataframe, but you'll need to account for specifics to the actual data you're working with. Maybe update your question with additional details or ask a new question if it's not directly related.